# ASP.NET Retrieve value using asp:button on Repeater

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a table which uses a repeater to display data. On each row there is a 'Delete' button which when clicked will retrieve the 'ClassId' from the row selected which will be used in a SQL DELETE query.

I don't know how to get the 'ClassId' from the row which was selected.

Snippet code from repeater:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<tr>

   <td>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LblTitle"Text='<%# Eval("ClassId")%>' />
   </td>

   <td>
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LblEmail" Text='<%# Eval("StartTime")%>' />
   </td>

   <td>
      <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label4" Text='<%# Eval("EndTime")%>' />
  </td>

  <td>
     <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("ClassDate")%>' />
  </td>

   <td>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" Text='<%# Eval("BuildingName")%>' />
  </td>

  <td>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label3" Text='<%# Eval("RoomCode")%>' />
  </td>

   <td>
   <asp:Button ID="deleteBtn" runat="server" OnClick="deleteBtn_Click" class="btn btn-danger" 
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ClassId") %>'Text="Delete" />
  </td>

</tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code on .cs page:

```
protected void deleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //SQL Delete query goes here using the ClassId to delete the row
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the ClassId in the CommandArgument, get it from there.

```
protected void deleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //SQL Delete query goes here using the ClassId to delete the row
     var classid = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;
}
```